# How to provide PathParm - jax-rs

Tags: java, web-services, jetty, jax-rs

How do you pass the variable in to the following methods

```
@Path("/entry-point")
public class EntryPoint
{
    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(EntryPoint.class);

    @GET
    @Path("test")
    public Response test(@PathParam("param") String param)
    {
        logger.info("Received message " + param);
        String output = "Hi : " + param;
        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{test2}")
    public String test2(@PathParam("param") String param)
    {
        logger.info("Received message " + param);
        return "yo";
    }
}
```

The following URL's give me null outputs for the parameters

http://localhost:8080/entry-point/test/ = hi null
http://localhost:8080/entry-point/test/value = 404 error

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to route the requests. So for example if I want to reach test method, this is the routing I need to do

```
http://localhost:8080/entry-point/test/thisIsTheStringPARAM
```

> The 'thisIsTheStringPARAM' part of the url is been retrieved by
>   '@PathParam("param")' and assigned to the String param.

Review the code below I have made some changes as well.

```
@Path("/entry-point")
public class EntryPoint
{
    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(EntryPoint.class);

    @GET
    @Path("/test/{param}")
    public Response test(@PathParam("param") String param)
    {
        logger.info("Received message " + param);
        String output = "Hi : " + param;
        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/test2/{param}")
    public String test2(@PathParam("param") String param)
    {
        logger.info("Received message " + param);
        return "yo";
    }
}
```